# How should I practically prepare/digest/view printed sheet music on a piano?

Tags: piano, digital-piano

This is more of a practical question, I've started practicing piano less then a week ago, I'm mostly printing sheet music to A4, folding it so it stays on the piano tray and playing it that way, however, this approach obviously doesn't work for 2+ pages

A folder that is able to stay open (don't have a tendency to fold itself) might work for multiple pages I guess, I would print, pierce and use the folder to view the sheet music, hard to find such a folder (it would also need to be minimally aesthetic, I haven't seen such a folder yet)

I'm asking this question to learn whether there is a right way to do this, a tool/special folder type that serves this purpose

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question but I've seen guitarists tape the sheets together in a row when there are 3 or more more pages. Also, a binder might work for holding many sheets and you can still turn the pages like a book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickly flip a page of sheet music while playing](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6/quickly-flip-a-page-of-sheet-music-while-playing)

Comment: I have just seen two methods: a 3-ring binder with sheet protectors holding a page front and back (you only get two pages at a time, though), or as someone else mentioned taping multiple sheets together side-by-side so they can be folded out and flipped over in various layouts.  When I took piano lessons, one of the things we covered was actually when and how to make a page-turn (usually a couple of bars before the end of the page - memorize what's left and do your best to play it as you reach up to turn).  In performance situations pianists frequently have an assistant there to turn pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing with notes for quite a while and in my opinion, the easiest thing to do is to put your sheets into a binder or a folder.
You could also use a foil for every sheet to make them heavier; the pages will be easier to flip then and you won't damage the paper either.

There is no "right way" to do it, just use a folder that isn't too big, so the pages can still be flipped quickly, and you will do just fine

Comment: I did some research on folders and found spiralled folders that have plastic A4 containers within, seemed like a perfect solution for the problem, both for containment and practical page switching, they didn't arrive yet but I'm hoping it will be the perfect solution for me, thanks for all the answers and comments, @Tim's wood plate method is also pretty interesting for continuous sheets

Answer (score 1):

Two sheets should be stuck together with 'sticky backed plastic', and ought to fit on the existing music stand on the piano. Occasionally, I have pieces that are 6 or more sheets long. These get 'Sellotaped' together like a concertina. I made, using a piece of thin plywood the width of the keyboard, and as high as an A4 sheet, with another strip attached to the bottom: a rather wide music stand. 3mm plastic is even more suited. Most long tunes are accommodated on this.If they need turning, it's easy because of the way the sheets are attached to each other. Better than in a ring binder or folder, where they need turning every 2 pages. An old trick used if the sheets want to escape from the stand is to use household clothes pegs to stop them.

Answer (score 1):

[Spiral binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_binding) that I have used for other purposes allows easy page flipping, especially if you use a heavier paper. It looks well, opens fully and easily at every page (flat on a desk without even thinking to fold itself) and can handle a lot of pages. You need a special machine for this but entry level models [like this](http://www.brack.ch/gbc-plastikbindegeraet-combbind-272551) seem not very expensive. I suggest to get any spiral-bound book and check how does it feel.

Answer (score 1):

Stick your A4 sheet music onto card. Then using gaffer tape or something else stick the cards together. This way you can have 2 3 or 4 sheets that will fold to A4 and still be solid enough to stand on music stand or piano etc.